# Getting values from ObservableCollection from another class

Tags: listview, xamarin, observablecollection

I am trying to create a list view for Recently Viewed Items. This will be on the Home page

**HomePage.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="recentKeyList" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:HomePage.RecentKeysList}" CachingStrategy="RetainElement"
                                      x:FieldModifier="public">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextCell Text="{Binding KeyName}" TextColor="Black" Detail="Subtext" DetailColor="{StaticResource Primary}" Tapped="RecentItem_Tapped"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
```

The **HomePage.Xaml.Cs** will use the getter method from KeysPage

```
static KeysPage KeysPageList = new KeysPage();
public static ObservableCollection<Key> RecentKeysList = KeysPageList.GetList;
```

The items that will be displayed in this list view will come from a different page (Keys page) depending on if it is tapped.

**KeysPage.Xaml.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<Key> RecentKeys = new ObservableCollection<Key>();
public HomePage HomePageList = new HomePage();

public ObservableCollection<Key> GetList {

        get
        {
            return RecentKeys;
        }

        set
        {
            RecentKeys = value;
        }
    }

    private async void Key_Tapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (listView.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        Key p = e.Item as Key;
        RecentKeys.Add(p); //Where we add to the observable collection

        HomePageList.recentKeyList.ItemsSource = RecentKeys;
     }
```

So essentially what I am trying to do is:

On the KeysPage when an item from the list view is selected, add it to the ObservableCollection (the whole Key object) and then in the home page create an object that calls the GetList method inside of Homepage.xaml.cs and display that observable collection in my list view but currently appears empty.

Comment: tightly coupling two pages together like this is a really bad design

Comment: Well I am new to Xamarin so i'm not sure what approach would be suitable if i wanted to create this sort of concept of having a display of recently viewed items on the home page depending on the items tapped on another page.

Comment: there are lots of ways to do this - the simplest might be to create a RecentItems collection in the App class, update it in the Keys page and read from it in the Home page

Comment: So for example in my App.xaml.cs i would have `public ObservableCollection<Key> RecentKeys = new ObservableCollection<Key>();` and then i would do something like `var app = new App();  app.RecentKeys.Add(p);` and then do `recentKeyList.ItemsSource = app.RecentKeys;` in my HomePage.xaml.cs?

Comment: the `App` class instance is always available via `App.Current`

Comment: Could you perhaps explain that point a bit further because App.Current has its own properties but how would you use this to access an element in App.xaml.cs

Comment: you have to cast it to access custom properties - `((App)App.Current).MyCustomProperty`

Comment: Thank you, i would like to accept your approach as an answer if you did create one but i got it working!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to display some data in ListView in KeysPage ContentPage, then may tap some ListView items, you want to create new ContentPage(HomePage) to display these Tap listView items recently.

I create simple sample that you can take a look.

Firstly, create Model class:

```
 public class KeyClass
{
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

Then create property `static ObservableCollection<KeyClass> recentkeys` in App.xaml.cs.

```
  public static ObservableCollection<KeyClass> recentkeys { get; set; }
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        recentkeys = new ObservableCollection<KeyClass>();
```

KeysPage:

```
 <ListView
            x:Name="listview1"
            ItemTapped="listview1_ItemTapped"
            ItemsSource="{Binding keys}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Detail="{Binding Detail}" Text="{Binding KeyName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="btn1_Clicked"
            Text="navigate" />

 public partial class KeysPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<KeyClass> keys { get; set; }
    public KeysPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        keys = new ObservableCollection<KeyClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            KeyClass key = new KeyClass() { KeyName = "key " + i, Detail = "key detailed " + i };
            keys.Add(key);
        }
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }  
    private void listview1_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listview1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            KeyClass key = e.Item as KeyClass;
            App.recentkeys.Add(key);            
        }
    }
    private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
    }
}
```

HomePage:

```
 public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public  ObservableCollection<KeyClass> recentkeys { get; set; }
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        recentkeys = new ObservableCollection<KeyClass>(App.recentkeys);
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}

   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding recentkeys}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding KeyName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```